# Show a div with Vue.js when a variable is equal to a value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want Vue.js to show a div only if the defined variable is set to a value, as of now I can use v-show="variable", and if that variable is set, it will show, but I'd like to be able to do v-show"variable=5", and have it show, is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

I'm kind of embarrassed, it was simply because I was using a single equal sign instead of a double equal sign. v-show="variable == 5" works.